# How can I get my class to pull the exact record that made the trigger run?

Tags: trigger, field-update, onchange

Trigger:

```
trigger UpdateLastActivitySubject_trigger on Lead (before update) {
List<Lead> lead = Trigger.new;

for (Lead ld : lead) {
    if (ld.Last_Activity_Date__c != trigger.oldMap.get(ld.Id)
       .Last_Activity_Date__c){
        UpdateLastActivitySubject_class.updateLead();
    }
}    
}
```

Class:

```
public class UpdateLastActivitySubject_class {

public static Lead getLead(){
  datetime myDateTime = datetime.now();

  Lead leadToUpdate;

  leadToUpdate =
      [SELECT Last_Activity_Subject__c, Id,
       Last_Activity_Date__c FROM Lead
       WHERE Last_Activity_Date__c = :myDateTime.Date()
       LIMIT 1];

  return leadToUpdate;

}

public static String getLatestSubject(Id leadId) {
    if (leadId == null) return '';

    List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, Subject, CreatedDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :leadId OR WhoId = :leadId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
    Task task = (tasks.size() == 1) ? tasks.get(0) : null;
    System.debug('Have tasks: ' + task);

    List<Event> events = [SELECT Id, Subject, CreatedDate FROM Event WHERE WhatId = :leadId OR WhoId = :leadId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
    Event event = (events.size() == 1) ? events.get(0) : null;
    System.debug('Have events: ' + event);

    String subject = '';
    if (task != null && event != null) {
        subject = task.CreatedDate > event.CreatedDate ? task.Subject : event.Subject;
    } else if (task != null) {
        subject = task.Subject;
    } else if (event != null) {
        subject = event.Subject;
    }

    return subject;
}

public static void updateLead() {
    Lead leadToUpdate;
    String subject;

    try {
        // Update lead with new activity
        leadToUpdate = getLead();

        subject = getLatestSubject(leadToUpdate.Id);

        // Update the subjct
        leadToUpdate.Last_Activity_Subject__c = subject;

        // Make the update call.
        update leadToUpdate;
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }

    // Verify that the update worked.
    Lead afterUpdate =
        [SELECT Last_Activity_Subject__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadToUpdate.Id];

    System.assertEquals(subject, afterUpdate.Last_Activity_Subject__c);

}
}
```

What I'm trying to do in that getLead() method is pull the record that sets off the trigger by matching it to a datetime. But this hasn't been working after I update a record's Last Activity (which will datestamp the Last Activity Date field).

The ultimate goal is to update that Last Activity Subject field. The method for that works, but maybe the surrounding code doesn't.

Comment: Prepare a list of lead records which satisfy your criteria and pass this list to method: `UpdateLastActivitySubject_class.updateLead();`.

Comment: For the updateLead method, how can I pull the Id field from that list?

Comment: Iterate through the list and use .id for example leadobj.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried writing an answer to explain to you all of the things wrong with your code but that answer became too long and I don't think that it fit really well in the format of this site. I wrote the below code as a sample of something I might actually put into a production org. Hopefully you can use this as a guide to learn from. **Disclaimer:** I don't expect this to be copy/paste if you get any errors you will have to adjust the code on your own

### LeadService.cls

```
public without sharing class LeadService {
    // before update so that we don't need to make any UPDATE calls
    public static void mostRecentActivitySummary(List<Lead> newLeads) {
        if (newLeads != null && !newLeads.isEmpty()) {
            // Use a subquery to pull tasks so that we can maintain the lead
            // to task relationship for ease of use, put into Id map
            // for ease of use
            Map<Id, Lead> leadsWithTasks = new Map<Id, Lead>([
                SELECT Id, (
                    SELECT Id, Subject, CreatedDate
                    FROM Tasks
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                FROM Lead
                WHERE Id IN :newLeads
            ]);

            for (Lead newLead : newLeads) {
                // If there are no tasks, there's no need to do anything
                if (
                    leadsWithTasks.get(newLead.Id) != null &&
                    !leadsWithTasks.get(newLead.Id).Tasks.isEmpty()
                ) {
                    // Make sure you're changing the newLead list and not
                    // the leads with task map. The newLead list are the actual
                    // isntances being updated, the map is just for reference
                    Task lastActivity = leadsWithTasks.get(newLead.Id).Tasks[0];
                    newLead.Last_Activity_Subject__c = lastActivity.Subject;
                    newLead.Last_Activity_Date__c = lastActivity.createdDate;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### LeadTrigger.trigger

```
Trigger LeadTrigger ON Lead(before update) {
    switch on Trigger.OperationType {
        WHEN BEFORE_UPDATE {
            // trigger.new contains all the leads in the current context
            // there's no reason to query leads, we just need to query tasks
            // we use a lead query with a task subquery as it helps keeps the 
            // relationships for ease of use
            LeadService.mostRecentActivitySummary(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

### TaskService.cls

```
// Service classes exist for organizing code and keeping triggers easy to read
public without sharing class TaskService {
    // After Insert And update
    public static void updateLeadsWithNewTasks(List<Task> newTasks, Map<Id, Task> oldTasks) {
        if (newTasks != null && !newTasks.isEmpty()) {
            Schema.SObjectType leadType = Lead.getSobjectType();
                // Used to make sure the task is associated to a lead
            List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
                // Used to keep track of leads that need to be updated

            for (Task newTask : newTasks) {
                if (
                    // First, make sure this task is for a lead
                    newTask.whoId != null && newTask.whoId.getSObjectType == leadType && (
                        oldTasks == null || // Insert Trigger
                        newTask.subject != oldTasks.get(newTask.Id).Subject 
                            // update trigger, Created date never changes
                    )
                ) {
                    // To avoid querying a lead, we can create a new instance
                    // and assign it the who Id, this also helps make sure
                    // that our update doesn't accidentally change a field on
                    // the lead when we don't want it to.
                    leadsToUpdate.add(new Lead(Id = newTask.whoId));
                }
            }

            // This update forces the lead trigger to fire. This will call the
            // above code from the lead service that does the rest of the work
            update leadsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

### TaskTriger

```
Trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after insert, after update) {
    switch on Trigger.OperationType {
        when AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE {
            // Old map contains a copy of the Task before the change so we can
            // compare to the new Task and see what, if anything, has changed
            TaskService.updateLeadsWithNewTasks(trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for writing all this out! I followed your code for TaskService and got hit with "A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: WhoId" on line 14. I'm guessing that has to do with `newTask.whoId.getSObjectType`. Is there a workaround for that? All I could think of was changing up this bit: `Id newTaskWho = newTask.whoId;
                if (
                    // First, make sure this task is for a lead
                    newTaskWho != null && newTaskWho.getSobjectType() == leadType && (`

Comment: WhoId I think is a polymorphic lookup which might be why you are getting the error. I think your solution of storing it in an ID variable first is a decent way to adress the issue. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah so that worked. What I'm trying to figure out now is a "method does not exist tor incorrect signature" error on the updateLeadsWithNewTasks call in TaskTrigger. Could it be that Trigger.oldMap isn't providing the Map<Id, Task> required by that method?

Comment: Probably not, if Trigger.oldMap doesn't exist the value is null and my code above is written to handle that. You'll have to provide the full error message text for me to help.

Comment: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void updateLeadsWithNewTasks(List<Task>, Map<Id,Task>) from the type TaskService"

Comment: The code I have above could not cause that error so there must be something in the implementation, make sure your service class exists and is a public class, make sure the method in public and defined with the static keyword, etc.

Comment: I think it was because I had my older class and trigger still up. Deleted those. Error cleared. Tested it out by logging an activity on a lead. That field updates perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To send the list of records to your class, you should prepare a list of such records which satisfy your trigger criteria. Below is example:

```
trigger UpdateLastActivitySubject_trigger on Lead (before update) {
List<Lead> lead = Trigger.new;
    List <Lead> lstLead = new List <Lead> ();
    for (Lead ld : lead) {
        if (ld.Last_Activity_Date__c != trigger.oldMap.get(ld.Id)
           .Last_Activity_Date__c){
            lstLead.add (ld);

        }
    }    
    UpdateLastActivitySubject_class.updateLead (lstLead);
}
```

Modify your existing class to accept the list of Lead Records:

```
public static void updateLead (List <Lead> lstLead)
```